# Enable password reset option for other authorities in jhipster

Tags: mysql, spring, jhipster

I could find a way to change the password for system generated admin only. How can I change this option enable for all the authorities in jhipster? As the given answer here I tried to find a change password method in UserResource.java. But couldn't find it. Now I could find it inside the password.state.js file. Still it not works for other roles though. After changing the AccountResource.java that also worked.

Comment: Thanks all. It works. It is inside password.state.js file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the default change password method generated by JHIPSTER, then, verify that the resource that call this method has this anotation of security @Secured("Admin") . You can remove this anotation to allow all users to change password.

Comment: You can also use several authorities like this: @Secured({"FOO", "BAR", ...})

Comment: In UserResource file couldn't find a change password method. So where should I get it?

Comment: Now I could find it inside the password.state.js file.

Comment: Still it not works for other roles though. Now for other admins it was resolved.

Comment: After changing the AccountResource.java that also worked.